# Need a Nested LINQ to XML query help

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have a XML file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<publisher>
<name>abc</name>
<link>http://</link>
<description>xyz</description>

<category title="Top">
<item>
<title>abc</title>
<link>http://</link>
<pubDate>1</pubDate>
<description>abc</description>
</item>

<item>
<title>abc</title>
<link>http://</link>
<pubDate>2</pubDate>
<description>abc</description>
</item>


</category>

<category title="Top2">
<item>
<title>abc</title>
<link>http://</link>
<pubDate>1</pubDate>
<description>abc</description>
</item>

<item>
<title>abc</title>
<link>http://</link>
<pubDate>2</pubDate>
<description>abc</description>
</item>
</category>

</publisher>
```

I need to write a LINQ to XML query in C# which returns everything under a "category" tag based on the value of attribute provided. I have tried the following code but it gives me error. Any help will be appreciated:

```
        System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        IEnumerable<string> items = from category in xml.Elements("category")
                    where category.Attribute("title").Value == "Top"
                    select category.ToString();
```

Comment: I am almost certain that select should come before where. Anyhow, paste in the error please.

Comment: "SELECT before WHERE" only SQL rule, not LINQ. Error description will help a lot. For me it's unclear why search for "Top" is done when there are no title with "Top" value. More source code could be fruitful too.

Comment: @Hamish @Budda: thanks for the response. This is what is returned in "items" once the query has been executed:


System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<TResult>.Current = 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directiv...


what i want is all the <items></items> tags returned depending upon the value of category given in the query. e.g. "Top", "Top2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   IEnumerable<string> items = from category in xml.Descendants("category") 
    where category.Attribute("title").Value == "Top" 
    select category.ToString();
```

Of course, that's going to give you a list with one string in it.  If you want just the string in it:

```
var items = (from category in xml.Descendants("category") 
            where category.Attribute("title").Value == "Top" 
            select category.ToString()).First();
```

But, if you want to continue processing the XML, you probably really want it as a XElement object:

```
var items = (from category in xml.Descendants("category") 
            where category.Attribute("title").Value == "Top" 
            select category).First();
```

Comment: thanks a bunch James!! the third query which you posted above was what I was looking for. It worked like a charm! thank you!